# почему не работает скрипт js?

Tags: javascript

есть js:

```
function Pympym(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#pym').html(data);
}

<input id="swal-input3" class="swal2-input" onkeyup = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\\d]/g,\'\'); Pympym(this.value); " >'
```

Первая часть onkeyup `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\\d]/g,\'\');` работает, а вторая нет. На функцию `Pympym` вообще говорит, что она `not defined`. Как я понимаю, вопрос в области видимости функции Pympym. Её надо сделать видимой для onkeyup. Прошу помощи)

=======================

вобщем должно работать, но не работает) Вот часть кода вырезнання из файла

```
$(document).ready(function () {
.....
    function pympym(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#pym').html(data);
    }

    $('#51').on('click', async function () {

        const ipAPI = '/site/gshu'
        Swal.queue([{
                title: 'Создать ссылку',
                html:
                        '<select id="swal-select1" class="swal2-select">' + Panel.tpr_options + '</select>' +
                        '<select id="swal-select2" class="swal2-select">' + Panel.act_options + '</select>' +
                        '<input id="swal-input3" class="swal2-input" onkeyup = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\\d]/g,\'\'); pympym(this.value); " >' +
                        '<div id = "pym"></div>',
                focusConfirm: false,
                confirmButtonText: 'Генерировать',
                confirmButtonColor: '#f7cd0099',
                customClass: {popup: 'my_swal_ok'},
//                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: () => {
.....
```

ошибок у меня нет в файле и функция объявлена до её вызова. Полный тест ошибки при событии keyup: "VM811:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: pympym is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (:2:47)". как бы всё банально и просто, но...

Answer (score 2):

Всё работает, как должно:

```js
function Pympym(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $('#pym').html(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="swal-input3" class="swal2-input" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,''); Pympym(this.value); ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто. Вы добавили Pympym скрипт где-то подальше и он не виден либо есть ошибка в скрипте до определения функции.

переместите его так чтоб во время запуска было видно.

Тест для примера отложенной занрузки.

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
eval(`
console.log("test");
  window.Pympym =
  function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#pym').html(data);
}`)}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="swal-input3" class="swal2-input" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,''); Pympym(this.value); ">
```

Зачем я создал свойство у window

```js
function sayHello(){ console.log("hello")};

console.log(window["sayHello"]);

window["sayHello"]()

window["sayHello"] = () => {console.log("hello and bye")}

sayHello()
```

Comment: вот у вас, кстати, та же проблема в консоли ""message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Pympym is not defined"," но при отложенном запуске потом приходит ответ. Тут как бы и вопрос: почему так? чего сразу не работает?

Comment: @Oughtem Так я имитировал отложенный запуск. В этом и вся идея

Comment: Я своим примером хотел показать что у вас метод не существует на момент вызова. А причин несколько. Код упал перед объявлением. Объявление идет позже вызов раньше ...

Comment: так как же не существует? он же раньше по коду идёт

Comment: Идти раньше по коду и выполняться раньше это не одно и тоже. Мой пример посмотрите

Comment: отложенная загрузка, как я понимаю, в вашем примере используется не как решение, а как метод дебага. Вы этим показываете, что функция не существует на момент её вызова, но через время начинает существовать. Также вы используете глобальный объект window. не совсем понятно для чего. Но то такое.... В качестве решения вы написали "переместите его так чтоб во время запуска было видно.". Функцию Pympym я потыкал уже где только можно, она всё равно не видна в момент запуска (хоть и не понятно почему). Куда её втыкнуть то чтоб видно было?

Comment: По умолчанию любая глобальная функция это свойство объекта window.  я создал совойство у window тем самым создал глобальный объект

Comment: так а куда её втыкнуть то надо, чтоб она видна была?

Comment: @Oughtem добавил примеров для ознакомления с window

Comment: у меня вопрос не в том, что такое window. Мне надо понять, куда вставить функцию, чтоб работало

Comment: Сделайте как я на объявлении вставьте window и функцию

Comment: @Oughtem я не знаю где там у вас ваша функция window.Pympym =
  function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#pym').html(data); } поможет

Answer (score 1):

перепробовал по всякому, не работает и всё) Хоть с window, хоть без него.
Сделал старым дедовским способом. Учитывая то, что данные динамические и на момент загрузки страницы отсутствуют обращаюсь к `$(document)`:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#swal-input3', function(){
    var data = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
    $(this).val(data);
    $('#pym').html(data);
})
```